# Asp.Net Repeater ItemCommand dataitem is always null

Tags: asp.net, repeater

In repeater `rpt_ItemCommand` Event the `e.Item.DataItem` is always null.

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void rpt_ItemCommand(Object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem // here the DataItem is Null.
}
```

Suggest me any solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DataItem Property is always null except ItemDataBound... its by design of Microsoft.

Answer (score 6):

Think of using CommandArgument.

```
<asp:LinkButton ToolTip="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' ....
```

and use it in ItemCommand Event as

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```